# How to remove parts of a string that are between two symbols?

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel VBA, I have the following data in a string:

```
<a title="" href="/player-profiles/ashley-barnes/" data-hasqtip="19" oldtitle="Ashley Barnes">Barnes (Ashley)</a>
```

I want to strip the a tags from the string so that I just end up with "Barnes (Ashley)"

I'm assuming the best way to do it would be to remove all characters between < and > symbols, including the symbols. How would I do that?

Comment: Are you pulling this through IE Automation ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest parsing this string as HTML and access what you need based on the actual DOM element:

```
Public Sub parsehtml()

    Set html = CreateObject("HTMLFile")

    html.body.innerHTML = "<a title="""" href=""/player-profiles/ashley-barnes/"" data-hasqtip=""19"" oldtitle=""Ashley Barnes"">Barnes (Ashley)</a>"

    MsgBox html.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).innerText 'Barnes (Ashley)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to determine the string characters that isolate your target. Use either `InStr` or `InStrRev`, then pull out the substring between them:

```
Sub ShowMe()
    Dim html As String
    html = "<a title="""" href=""/player-profiles/ashley-barnes/"" data-hasqtip=""19"" oldtitle=""Ashley Barnes"">Barnes (Ashley)</a>"

    Dim pos1 As Long
    Dim pos2 As Long
    Dim nameOnly As String
    pos1 = InStrRev(html, "</a>")
    pos2 = InStrRev(html, ">", pos1) + 1
    nameOnly = Mid$(html, pos2, pos1 - pos2)
    Debug.Print nameOnly
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function KillJunk(S As String) As String
    Dim L As Long, s2 As String, CH As String
    Dim Ignore As Boolean, i As Long

    Ignore = False
    L = Len(S)

    For i = 1 To L
        CH = Mid(S, i, 1)
        If CH = "<" Then
            Ignore = True
        End If
        If Ignore Then
            If CH = ">" Then
                Ignore = False
            End If
        Else
            s2 = s2 & CH
        End If
    Next i
    KillJunk = s2
End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to accomplish this as well

> You will need to have added a VBA reference to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions x.x"

```
Sub StripTags()
    Dim htm As String: htm = "<a title="""" href=""/player-profiles/ashley-barnes/"" data-hasqtip=""19"" oldtitle=""Ashley Barnes"">Barnes (Ashley)</a>"
    Dim Regex As New RegExp: Regex.Global = True: Regex.Pattern = "<.*?>"
    Debug.Print Regex.Replace(htm, "")
End Sub
```